# Global Javascript File for Facebook Pixel

Tags: javascript, facebook, dotnetnuke

I am currently dealing with a conundrum involving DNN.  I had recently asked a question about it but I had to reassess.  Is there anyway to create a global script file that not only fires the facebook pixel page view but the custom events based off which button elements are clicked? (such as add to cart, view product, check out etc) then inject said global file to every page of an Ecommerce site?

Comment: You would include the js file in the header or other elements of your site that repeat on all the pages you want this to run on.

Comment: Yea but I'm trying to make a file that fires the elements based on specific elements. The initial pixel will still have to be in all the headers

Answer (score 0):

You already have the initial pixel in all headers, so that's a good start. You can create a separate js file and include it in your skin, and in that js file, use conditional statements to check for specific buttons/links or other specific click events, and put the relevant pixel event code to fire.

For example, assuming you have 'add to cart' buttons on the site with the css class .addToCartButton, you could use:

```
$('.addToCartButton').click(function() {
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart');
});
```

You can do similar things for every event you want to track.

Comment: I'm still new to DNN...so which folder would i place the js file? just in the file labelled Js and then create the script source in the default file?

Comment: In your DNN directory, go to your skin path directory, which is:
 `/Portals/_default/Skins/<YourCurrentSkin>`

For simplicity sake, place the js file in that folder. Assuming you called it pixelevents.js, you can open up all your .ascx files and in each of them you can add:

`<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="pixelevents.js" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" />`

Comment: so I do have to add it to every .ascs files? Most of those are in the default skin folder right? and typically they have a js file too?

Comment: well did everything suggested and still couldn't get it to fire raw :(

Comment: If you need a hand, send me an email!